# ReactJS. Render component on click in another component (based on class toggle)

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I need to render the component on click in another component like this:

I have the `DevStatus` component which is just the two bootstrap radiobuttons. And I have `IssuesList` component that is the boostrap list.

[codepen code](http://codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/pen/JdgqmP?editors=001), [full page view](http://s.codepen.io/yakovenkodenis/debug/JdgqmP?)

So, when a user clicks on one of the radiobuttons, I need the `IssuesList` component to be rendered with another data (`closed_issues` array for the `Closed Issues` radiobutton and `open_issues` array for the `Open Issues` radiobutton). I'm new to React, but I think I'll have just to change the component's state and it will trigger the rerender, is that correct?

However, I can't manage to link the state of the `IssuesList` with click event on the `DevStatus`. Could you help me with doing that?

Also, those `closed_issues` and `open_issues` arrays will actually be the jQuery ajax responses from `$.getJSON` method. How can I implement this data getting process so that it doesn't block the UI thread and actually does get rendered when the JSON response is received?

This is how I'm going to get the JSON:

```
function _getIssues() {
    let issues = $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/org_name/project/issues?state=all&filter=all')
                  .done( (data) => { issues = data } );
    return issues;
}
```

So, I'll get just one array of all issues and after that I'll need to split it into two. But to do that, I'll first need to call `_getIssues()` method which at first will return the array of `undefined` and after some milliseconds that array will become the valid data. However, I think that would be enough to break the app and React will not render the array of `undefined`. If this assumption is correct, how do I avoid it?

## Update

Now I have this:

```
class DevStatus extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      issues: [{title: '', html_url: '#', state: 'open'}]
    };
    this.CLOSED_ISSUE_ID = 'closed_issue_r';
    this.OPEN_ISSUE_ID = 'open_issue_r';
  }

  getIssues(p_url, p_data, cbSuccess) {
    console.log('getIssues');
    let request = $.ajax({
      url: p_url,
      method: "GET",
      data: p_data
    });
    request.done(cbSuccess);
    request.fail(console.log);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/repo/project/issues?state=all&filter=all';
    this.getIssues(url, {issues: 'open'}, this.onBackendResponse.bind(this));
  }

  onBackendResponse(data) {
    console.log('onBackendResponse');
    this.issues = data;
    this.setState({ issues: data });
  }

  onChangeRadioButton(e) {
    console.log('onChangeRadioButton')
    console.log(e.target.id);
    switch(e.target.id) {
      case OPEN_ISSUE_ID:
        this.setState({ issues: this.getOpenedIssues(this.issues).bind(this) });
        break;
      case CLOSED_ISSUE_ID:
        this.setState({ issues: this.getClosedIssues(this.issues).bind(this) });
        break;
    }
  }

  getClosedIssues(issues) {
    console.log('filter closed');
    return issues.filter((issue) => { issue.state === 'open' });
  }

  getOpenedIssues(issues) {
    console.log('filter opened');
    return issues.filter((issue) => { issue.state === 'closed' });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.issues);
    return (
      <div className="dev-status-page col-centered">
        <div className="issues col-centered">
          <div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label className="btn btn-primary active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id={this.CLOSED_ISSUE_ID}
                     autoComplete="off" onChange={this.onChangeRadioButton.bind(this)}/> Closed Issues
            </label>
            <label className="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id={this.OPEN_ISSUE_ID}
                     autoComplete="off" onChange={this.onChangeRadioButton.bind(this)} /> Open Issues
            </label>
          </div>
          <IssuesList issues={this.state.issues} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class IssuesList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    let issues = this.props.issues.map( (item, index) => {
      return (
        <a key={index} className="list-group-item"
           href={item.html_url} target="_blank">
          {item.title}
        </a>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="list-group">
        {issues}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

IssuesList.propTypes = {
  issues: React.PropTypes.array
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: yes changing the state is exactly what you should do. Changing the state with this.setState invokes the render method again.

You could do something like this:

```
var CLOSED_ISSUE_ID = 'closed_issue_r', OPEN_ISSUE_ID = 'open_issue_r';
var getAsyncDataFromBackend = function(p_url, p_data, cbSuccess){
  var request = $.ajax({
                   url: p_url,
                   method: "POST",
                   data: p_data
                });
      request.done(cbSuccess);
}
//..
getInitialState:function(){
  //empty state so App doesnt <quote>break</quote>
  return {issue_data:[]}
},
componentWillMount:function(){
  //init component with open issues
  //will be executed emediately before render.
  getAsyncDataFromBackend(url, {issues: 'open'}, this.onBackendResponse);
},
render:function(){
  return (
    <button id={OPEN_ISSUE_ID} onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton}>opened</button>
    <button id={CLOSED_ISSUE_ID} onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton}>closed</button>
    <IssueList list={this.state.issue_data} />
  )
},
onChangeRadioButton: function(e){
  switch(e.target.id){
    case OPEN_ISSUE_ID:
      getAsyncDataFromBackend(url, {issues: 'open'}, this.onBackendResponse);
      break;
    case CLOSED_ISSUE_ID:
      getAsyncDataFromBackend(url, {issues: 'closed'}, this.onBackendResponse);
      break;
  }
},
onBackendResponse(data){
  this.setState({issue_data: data});
}
//...
```

In your method `getAsyncDataFromBackend` you will most likely encapsulate some ajax code.

So all you do in your render function of your react component is calling the `<IssueList list={this.state.issue_data} />` component.

I Hope this helped?

EDIT2: I've done some more code examples for AJAX and the rendering part to make it more obvious.

Hope that you catch me now.

Comment: Could you please tell me how should I change my ajax method in `IssuesList` component and how should be the `onChangeRadioButon` method be used?

Comment: And, if I understand your code correctly, every click on the radiobutton will trigger the ajax request?

Comment: How you apply this onto your buttons is up to you. You could have a <button id="open_issue_r" onClick={this.onChangeRadioButton}>show open issues</button> and one for the closed issues. in Your getAsyncDataFromBackend you could also do some caching if you dont want to query backend every time. You dicide what is best for your purpose. So to keep it short inside your getAsyncDataFromBacken function pass the parameters you provided to an AJAX call. You could for example use this for requesting resources: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Could you please see the update in the question? I tried to do everything according to your answer (and tried to do the caching), but this still doesn't work. It throws the error `this.props.issues.map` and I assume that this is because the function is preformed on the array of `undefined`. Could you please help me to find out what's wrong in my code?

Comment: 'this.props.issues.map' should be 'this.state.issues.map'.

Comment: Why? we pass the data to the `IssuesList` component through `props`, don't we? And when I change it ot `this.state.issues`, it throws `Cannot read property 'issues' of null`

Answer (score 1):

The most sane solution, while staying within react and not doing flux or state containers, is to pass the data all the way up to the first common parent, and then down again to the consuming component

send in a callback in props to the component with the radio buttons, fire it from within the done-callback in the ajax call with the changes and then the parent can update its state and re render the child with the new data.

EDIT: with the update the question changed to another solution, this was about how you trigger re-renders in siblings/parents when state/data changes in one component.

Comment: Could you go into more detail please? I changed my ajax function in `IssuesList` component. But what do I change in render methods, what are the `onNewData(data)` and `handleNewData(d)` methods should look like? And how would I trigger the state change?

Comment: handleNewData just need to do this.setState({issues:data}) with the new data and render need pass this.state.issues to IssueList. Ive edit my example with that!